# The logic of clicking like in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

world! I want to make sure that the like is placed only on one card, and not on all at once. I wrote the logic of painting the like and clicking it. But this applies to all cards, not just the one where I clicked like.

How can I change the logic so that the like is placed only on the card I clicked on?

Below the code CellView() is a cell with a card, which I then use in another view

```
struct CellView: View{
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @AppStorage("isLiked") var isLiked: Bool = false

    var data: Model
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            VStack{
                AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: data.photo)!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("GrayWhite"), lineWidth: 0.5)
                    )
            }.background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            
            
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    
                    Text("\(data.price) ₽")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                            self.isLiked.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                            .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .black)
                    })
                }.padding(.bottom, 1)
                
                HStack{
                    Text(data.company)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack{
                    Text(data.name)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 2)
        }
        .padding(5)  
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The isLiked var is global to app. It should be in your data model associated with the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cell has to be identified for Swift to know what is liked.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardData: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    // add the rest of the data associated with the cards, company, etc.
    
}
```

And if we want to follow the MVVM-structure you create a separate file for the functions (when we check like and unlike each card).

```
class CellViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var card: CardData!
    @Published var isLiked = false
    
    func like() {
        isLiked.toggle()
    }
    
  
    
  
}
```

Now all our CellViews can be liked seperately (I removed some your inputs, for test)

```
struct CellView: View{
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    
    @ObservedObject var cellViewModel: CellViewModel = CellViewModel()
    
    init(cardData: CardData) {
        self.cellViewModel.card = cardData
        
    }

    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("GrayWhite"), lineWidth: 0.5)
                    )
            }.background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            
            
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    
                    Text(" ₽")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        cellViewModel.like()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: cellViewModel.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                            .foregroundColor(cellViewModel.isLiked ? .red : .black)
                    })
                }.padding(.bottom, 1)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("company")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack{
                    Text("name")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 2)
        }
        .padding(5)
    }
}
```

Testing liking seperately:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            CellView(cardData: CardData())
            CellView(cardData: CardData())
            CellView(cardData: CardData())
            CellView(cardData: CardData())
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but could you change a little? 
I already have `var id: String = UUID().UUIDString` in `class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable { ... }` 
And I use this class everywhere with the help of `var data: Model`  
And in ContentView I use as: `CellView(data: model)`

Comment: Your `class Model` does not need to be `Identifiable`.  It is actually your view model, and should contain the logic. `CardData` needs to be `Identifiable`. Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/).

Comment: Like @Yrb says. The id shouldn´t be in the ViewModel. Classes are reference types (each instance will share the data), and structures are value types (each instance will be a unique copy of the data).

Comment: All the data you want to pass into the cells should be in the CardData (id, company name, price) and all the changes for that specific View should be in the CellViewModel (the functions to change the view: like, disslike, check the amount of likes). @ruzaykina

Comment: I figured it out and everything worked out! Thank you for your comments and special thanks for the detailed answer.